# Combination of JSON values to different HTML tables

Tags: javascript, html, json, sum

I have a JSON file.

```
["plat1","chan1","group1","a","cat1","a","a",26,1000],
["plat1","chan2","group1","a","cat2","a","a",70,14],
["plat1","chan1","group1","a","cat1","a","a",14,1000],
["plat1","chan1","group2","a","cat1","a","a",50,2000],
["plat1","chan1","group2","a","cat2","a","a",30,2000],
["plat1","chan1","group2","a","cat1","a","a",30,2000]
```

Each object has 3 basic columns and 1 column with a number. I want the rows to merge depending on the combination of the 3 columns and then return the SUM of the numeric column. The combinations are the following:

```
plat1, group1, cat1
plat1, group1, cat2
plat1, group2, cat1
plat1, group2, cat2
```

etc

I am trying to present each case (combination) in different HTML tables but my code seems to fail even if I replace the regex with '=='.

```js
var data = {
  "headers":["Plat","Chan","Group","Random","Cat","Random","Random","num","num2"],
  "rows":[  
 ["plat1","chan1","group1","a","cat1","a","a",26,1000],
 ["plat1","chan2","group1","a","cat2","a","a",70,14],
 ["plat1","chan1","group1","a","cat1","a","a",14,1000],
 ["plat1","chan1","group2","a","cat1","a","a",50,2000],
 ["plat1","chan1","group2","a","cat2","a","a",30,2000],
 ["plat1","chan1","group2","a","cat1","a","a",30,2000]
  ]
};

function transformData(rows) {
  const 
    rowMap = new Map(),
    result = [];
    
  // Iterate over the rows.
  rows.forEach(row => {
    const
      // Create a key, it is the first elements joined together.
      key = row.slice(0,4).join();
      
    // Check if the Map has the generated key...
    if (rowMap.has(key)) {
      // The map has the key, we need to add up the values
      const
        // Get the value for the current key.
        storedRow = rowMap.get(key);
        // Add the value of the current row to the row in the map.
        storedRow[7] += row[7];
  storedRow[8] += row[8];
    } else {
      // The key doens't exist yet, add the row to the map.
      rowMap.set(key, row);
    }
  });
  
  // Iterate over all the entries in the map and push each value with the
  // summed up value into the array.
  rowMap.forEach(value => {
    result.push(value);
  });
    
 //First table - group1 for Views
 var table1 = '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #e90649; width: 117px;">&nbsp;</div><div class="col-lg-6" style="max-width: 100px; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 2vw;">group1<br/><br/><span style="font-size: 1vw;">Cat1</span></div><div class="col-lg-6"><div class="container"><table><thead><tr><th>Plat</th><th>Chan</th><th>Group</th><th>Num</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
 
 for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
 {
  platformJSON = JSON.stringify(result[i][0]);
  objJSON = JSON.stringify(data.rows[i][2]);
  rateJSON = JSON.stringify(data.rows[i][4]);

  if(platformJSON.match(/plat1/) && objJSON.match(/group1/) && rateJSON.match(/cat1/))
  {
   table1 +="<tr><td>" + result[i][0] + "</td><td>" + result[i][1] +"</td><td>" + result[i][2] + "</td><td>" + result[i][7] + "</td><td>" + "</td></tr>";
  }

 }
 
 table1 += '</tbody></table></div></div></div>';
 $("#three").html(table1);

  // Return the array.
  return result;
  
}

data.rows = transformData(data.rows);
const
  generateHTML = createTable(data);
$("#one").html(generateHTML);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

body { 
    margin: 0;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: Roboto; }
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 241px; 
    background-color:#454545;
}
.row > .col-lg-6 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.container {
  /*display: flex;*/
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 20px);
  text-align: left;
}

/*img {
    padding-left: 7%;
    max-height:55px;
    width:auto;
}*/
td{
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border: none;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#454545;
  font-weight:500;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing:0.3em 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}
tr{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
tr:nth-child(1) {
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
 
#one,#two,#three,#four{
    padding-top:2%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<div id="three"></div>
```

I can see a row that contains results for the group2 which should be excluded after the IF statement.

Comment: With your example data, you would get three tables? Two tables with 1 row and one table with 2 rows. Perhaps you can add an example of the expected output?

Comment: @Thijs The script is showing only one example. I have added one more line in the JSON. If I make it work for the first version (plat1, group1,cat1) then I can just copy-paste the script for the other versions.

Comment: And which values have to be tallied up?

Comment: @Thijs The second line in my snippet should not populate. The statement should exclude it: if(platformJSON.match(/plat1/) && objJSON.match(/group1/) && rateJSON.match(/cat1/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong part was here:

```
platformJSON = JSON.stringify(result[i][0]);
objJSON = JSON.stringify(data.rows[i][2]);
rateJSON = JSON.stringify(data.rows[i][4]);
```

and it has to be replaced with:

```
platformJSON = JSON.stringify(result[i][0]);
objJSON = JSON.stringify(result[i][2]);
rateJSON = JSON.stringify(result[i][4]);
```

And also the key had to be extended to cover more fields:

```
key = row.slice(0,5).join();
```